# Using Linq to select from a List in a List with Contains

Tags: linq, select, lambda, any

I'm having syntax troubles.

```
public class Student
{
   int StudentId;
   string Name;
}

public class Course
{
   int CourseId;
   List<Student> Students;
}


int[] studentIds = { 5, 7, 12 };
List<Course> allCourses = myDataContext.Courses.ToList();
```

Using *Lambda expressions* or *query expressions*, how do I get a filtered list of all the Courses containing any of the Students in the array `studentIds`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = from course in allCourses
             where course.Students.Any(x => studentIds.Contains(x.StudentId))
             select course;
```